# PostgreSQL RDS running out of Free Storage Space while querying

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a read-only PostgreSQL RDS database which is heavily queried. We don't perform any inserts/updates/deletes during normal traffic, but still we can see how we are running out of Free Storage Space and an increase on Write IOPS metric. During this period, CPU usage is at 100%.

At some point, the storage space seems to be released.

Is this expected?

[image]

Comment: My guesses would be sorts that spill to disk (e.g. a `union` where a `union all` should be) usually caused by bad joins that create huge cartesian products.  I would log your long running queries with a high threshold (10+ seconds?) and then review their SQL for correctness:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-query-logging/

Comment: Thanks @MikeOrganek for the comment. It is resolved now. It was not about ```union``` or ```union all``` but about the log level we set. So the link you set in the comment helped to find the issue anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the end related to our logs. `log_statement` was set to all, where every single query to PG would be log. In order to troubleshoot long time queries, we combined `log_statement` and `log_min_duration_statement`.

Since this is a read only database we want to know if there is any insert/update/delete operation, so `log_statement: dll` ; and we want to know which queries are taking longer than 1s: `log_min_duration_statement: 1000`